# refresh pivot table when cell changes

Tags: vba, excel

I need to refresh the pivot table when some cells are modify. What I wrote was the following:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("C3:C6")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        Worksheets("Pivot_Graf").PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotCache.Refresh   

    End If

End Sub
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you placing the code in the code pane for  Worksheets("Dashboard")?

Answer (score 1):

Provided you place the code in the Worksheets("Dashboard") code pane, as for the intersect you are looking for target to be within keycells range, the following should work. You don't need Target.Address as your are comparing against KeyCells as a range object.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("C3:C6")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then

        Worksheets("Pivot_Graf").PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotCache.Refresh

    End If

End Sub
```

Notice: If placed in the correct pane you can also drop

```
Worksheets("Dashboard").
```

from in front of

```
Set KeyCells =  Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("C3:C6")
```

Comment: Still doesn't work ... when I change one of the cells (Range ("C3: C6")), it doesn't automatically update the pivot table...
The cells C3: C6 are data validation. Maybe it doesn't understand that the cell are different because of that?

Comment: I tested with data validation and it still fires the event

Comment: Is your code in the code pane for dashboard? See example here https://ufile.io/ptce7

Comment: Did the link clarify things?

Comment: the code wasn't working because it was in a module and not in the worksheet "dashboard". but now it works! thank you! :)